# Request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate") Returns Null

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, client, certificate

I have an issue with Request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate") returning NULL for some users during client certificate authentication and a valid certificate for others.  For the users where this failed, if we delete and rebuild their Windows user profile, the problem get fixed.  There is a workaround for this issue but I was hoping to avoid having our users rebuild their Windows account profile.  Is there a specific setting in IE or ActivIdentity that might be causing IE to not sent the client certificate?  We're using IE8 and ActivIdentity 6.1 on Windows 7 with Tomcat 6.

Thanks.

Tri

Comment: You might try setting clientAuth="true" on the HTTPS connector in your Tomcat config, which will reject clients without a certificate, but I don't know if that would result in any different behavior on the client end.

Comment: Did you figure it out, @Tri Phan? If so, please share your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your clients must configure ActivClient to make their certificates available to Windows. The **Tools | Advanced | Make Certificates Available to Windows** menu item will do this.

Comment: Did this work? Also, @Mermeister, what about situations where the client sometimes makes its certificate available? Sometimes my client's HTTP requests include the certificate, but other times it will not